# Number shows up as NaN instead of the number in my variable

Tags: javascript, html

I need it to show up as "0" before you click, and for some reason, it shows up as NaN, help!

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>

  var money = 0;
  var clickingPower = 10; 
    
    function moneyClick() {
    var clicks = clicks + 1;
    
        document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money + clickingPower * clicks;
    }
    
  </script>
</head>

  <h1>You have <span id="money"></span> dollars</h1>
  
  <button onclick="moneyClick()">Click to make money</button>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you initialized the variable clicks?

Comment: `var clicks = clicks + 1;` <---

Answer (score 3):

It this line

```
   var clicks = clicks + 1
```

Your variable clicks does not exist yet, that is why you get NaN

Comment: it still shows up as NaN even though i defined the variable

Comment: How did you define it you need to set it to some number for it to be number. Since you are adding i reccomend setting it to 0 since it is neutral when adding and it does not mess up the result

Answer (score 2):

You're using `clicks` before defining it.

you can try this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>

        var money = 0;
        var clickingPower = 10; 

        function moneyClick() {
            var clicks = (clicks || 0) + 1;

            document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money + clickingPower * clicks;
        }

    </script>
    </head>

    <h1>You have <span id="money"></span> dollars</h1>

    <button onclick="moneyClick()">Click to make money</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, it works! Is there a way to make it update with 10 more money every time I click?

Comment: @embers02 you can use `var clicks = (clicks || 0) + clickingPower;` . Your code isn't clean by the way try to optimize it

Comment: I did it. Is there anything i can improve upon?

Comment: you can start by putting your `script` tag at the end. This way it can't block your HTML. and use Javascript to add events.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize the variable `clicks`:

```
var clicks = 0;
function moneyClick() {
clicks = clicks + 1;

    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money + clickingPower * clicks;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your variable. Make sure you put this outside of your function.
Var clicks = 0

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script>
      var money = 0;
      var clicks = 0;
      var clickingPower = 10; 
    
        function moneyClick() {
        clicks = clicks + 1;
    
         document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money + clickingPower * clicks;
        }
    
     </script>
```